# Display users related to territory on Account

Tags: account, sharing-rule

I have 2 standard objects, Accounts and Users and the Territory object. Accounts and Users have a lookup to the Territory. I need to display the user only accounts from his territory. How correctly to setup sharing rules?

Comment: "I need to display the user only accounts from his territory", can you please shade some light on this?

Comment: The Territory has records (Spain, France, Germany). 
Each user has a link to the territory. Each Account is the same. I need to display the user only accounts with his territory

Comment: Where do u want to display that?

Comment: On the standard salesforce page(tabs) Account

Comment: Why do you think you need sharing rules with your requirement?

Comment: I dont know. I think sharing rules can help me. I will be happy with any help.

Answer (score 0):

With the current model, as described by you, on **account** standard page you will have the territory field, as it is parent. Since , user is the child of territory, you’ll need to create a VF page with account standards controller and an extension controller.

In the extension controller, get the users against the territory of the current account.

```
public myControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    account acc = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
// query the territory against account

// Query the users against territory retrieved above 

// display the users on vf page
}
```

Finally, edit the page layout and put your vf page on the desired location to have the users related to the territory.

**Edit**

You could also use a VF page without a controller, as I learned that recently

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Accoount"> 
    <apex:relatedList subject="{!Account.Territory__c}" list="Users"/> 
</apex:page>
```

Salesforce defines the `subject` in [`<apex:relatedList>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm) as

> **Subject** - The parent record from which the data and related list definition are
>   derived. If not specified, and if using a standard controller, this
>   value is automatically set to the value of the ID query string
>   parameter in the page URL.